# Time complexity analysis for finding the maximum element

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, lower-bound

I've encountered a homework problem:

> which of these is an asymptotically tight upper bound for the best-case running time of an optimal algorithm that finds the maximum element in an arbitrary array of integers of size `n`
>
> 1. O(log n)
> 2. O(n<sup>2</sup>)
> 3. O(n)
> 4. O(1)
> 5. O(n log n)

Based on my understanding, it's O(n) since even it's the best-case we still need
to scan over the arr to get the result. Please correct me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. One way to see this is via an *adversarial argument*. Suppose that you have an algorithm that allegedly finds the maximum value in the array, but doesn't inspect every array element at least once.

Suppose I run your algorithm on some array A<sub>1</sub> that consists of nothing but the number 0. Since your algorithm doesn't look at all positions in the array, there's some position it doesn't look at; call that position k. Now, define A<sub>2</sub> to be an array that's the same as array A<sub>1</sub>, except that the element at position k in A<sub>2</sub> is defined to be 1.

Now, what happens if I run your algorithm on A<sub>2</sub>? Since your algorithm never looked at position k in A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> is identical to A<sub>2</sub> except at position k, your algorithm can't tell A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> apart. Therefore, whatever it says for A<sub>1</sub> must be the same as what it says for A<sub>2</sub>.

That's a problem, though. If your algorithm says that the maximum value is 0, then it's wrong for A<sub>2</sub>, whose max is 1. If your algorithm says that the maximum value is 1, then it's wrong for A<sub>1</sub>, whose max is 0. Therefore, the algorithm has to be wrong in at least one case, so it can't be a correct algorithm for finding the maximum value.

This argument shows that any deterministic algorithm that always finds the maximum value in an array must look at all positions in that array, so the runtime must be Ω(n) to be correct.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

O(n) is the running time if we know nothing about the data in the array. Which in your case is true. "an arbitrary array of integers of size n" implies that it could be any integer array.

O(1) is possible when the array is sorted.
O(nlog n) is possible if we first use quicksort to sort the array and then select the largest item.
O(n^2) is possible if we first sort the array using bubblesort and then just select the largest item.

Comment: You state: "O(nlog n) is possible if we first use quicksort to sort the array and then select the largest item. O(n^2) is possible if we first sort the array using bubblesort and then just select the largest item."

Yes, every complexity upper than O(n) is possible if you apply a wrong algorithm, but this is not the complexity of finding the maximum in an unsorted array